# Gaps created by cement-board being further that the bathtub-lip when tiling?

Tags: tile, bathtub, thinset

My installation: Cement-board = over the bathtup lip.

There's one-two spots where the cement-board is not not flush with the bathtub lip creating gaps behind few tiles are supposed to be.
Can i just apply more Thinset mortar at those spots to compensate ?
It's not huge, but just enough to bother me because it ain't flat.
Thank you

Andrew

[image]

Comment: I would add some thinset and get it flat first let it dry then tile less chance of having a problem with the tile this way.

Comment: The backerboard was installed incorrectly, but we're past that now. Let the *fudging* begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your way or Ed Beal's are fine & do work. You just don't want any voids or unsupported portions of tile to avoid impact cracking or breaking. Back-buttering & going to a wider trowel notch should do it. But otherwise, mark your layout if you fill-in, to make sure you're actually filling to the row's edge.